# Refreshing android fragment after resume

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment in my MainActivity with ListView the content of which is browsed from a database. The method getUpdates() gets the data from database and then that data is applied to ListView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    getUpdates();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_list, container , false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.testListView);
    ...
    return v;
}
```

When other Activity is launched the database is changed, but when the activity is closed and the `MainActivity` is resumed I cant see the updates in the Fragment. So the `onCreateView` method is not called. But I need to update the View of fragment in onResume() method. How can I do that? Or if there is another more efficient way with using listeners , please give me to know.

Answer (score 1):

Your fragments that rely on these events could implement an interface that your activity can call (or you can have a base fragment that provides the overridable function). When your activity needs to trigger a refresh on your Fragment, just call the function and handle it in the Fragment.

You could do it with broadcasts, but that seems a bit overkill if the notifications aren't coming from a service.